# Scrollbar in WPF C# only let scroll to half of the content

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview, sizing

So I built the following code, which basically a sign up formular with a lot of TextBlocks, TextBoxes and Combo-boxes. All of them are wrapped up in a Grid, which is packed into a scrollview:

```
<Window x:Class="PatientenEditor.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PatientenEditor"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
     Title="MainWindow" Height="1119" Width="1000">

        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Background="White" Height="1119">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4516*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                
               //here is all the content, too much to put it in here and also not relevant
    
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Window>
```

And basically the problem looks like to following:
[screenshot from the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjDhs.jpg)

You can see in the image, that a lot of content is missing. It should be arround 8 topics, but as you can see it only lets me scroll to topic 3. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you hard-coding the height of the grid?

Comment: Remove Height="1119" from Grid

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @zia khan and @Panagiotis Kanavos for the solution!

The solution is:

Removing the 'hight' value from Grid.